# Instance of Paper elements in dart

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, paper-elements

How can I get an instance to the `paper-input` element below?

HTML file:

```dart
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <!-- <script src='packages/web_components/platform.js'></script>
       not necessary anymore with Polymer >= 0.14.0 -->
  <script src='packages/web_components/dart_support.js'></script>    
  <link rel='import' href='packages/paper_elements/paper_input.html'>
  <script src='packages/browser/dart.js'></script>
</head>
<body fullbleed unresolved>
  <paper-input id='subject' label='subject'></paper-input>
  <script type='application/dart' src='myscript.dart'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

myscript.dart:

```dart
import 'dart:html';
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';
import 'package:paper_elements/paper_input.dart';
export 'package:polymer/init.dart';
PaperInput _subject = querySelector('#subject');    // exception
void main() {
  ...
}
```

This causes an exception:

```dart
Breaking on exception: type 'HtmlElement' is not a subtype of type 'PaperInput'
```

Casting from HtmlElement to PaperInput does not work. Suggestions have included using `shadowRoot.querySelector('#subject');` and other `shadowRoot` usages, but where does it come from? If I append `.shadowRoot.querySelector('paper-input')` to the last line of myscript.dart, the element is null. Same result if I use the id instead of tag name. The element itself is top-level to the html body, so it is not in any other shadowRoot.

There is no way to get the contents of the `paper-input` without it being of the class PaperInput. But there seems no way to cast it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You run into [how to implement a main function in polymer apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20982489)

When you do it like shown below or inside a Polymer element (`attached()` after `super.attached()` or in some click or other event handler (when the element is properly initialized)

```dart
main() {
  initPolymer().run(() {
    // code here works most of the time
    Polymer.onReady.then((_) {     
      // some things must wait until onReady callback is called
      // for an example look at the discussion linked below

      PaperInput _subject = querySelector('#subject');
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: xD I was using that for the rest of manipulating the elements, but not for initial assignment. It looks like this will be the answer, thanks for all your time!!